# Are $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ in example 6 free variables?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure about the concept of a free variable because I haven't seen a term "free variable" mentioned in a set theory book or a discrete mathematics book.

Are all $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ in example 6 free variables?

Comment: No, only $x_3$. Note that $x_4$ has to be one particular value (3), whereas $x_3$ can be any value whatsoever. After that, $x_2$ can only have one particular value (once $x_3$ and $x_4$ has been determined) and $x_1$ can have only one value (once $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$ have been determined.

Comment: No, only $x_3$ is. All other variables are fixed or dependent on this value.

Comment: Obviously, $x_4$ is not free, since its value is fixed. If you eliminate $x_4$ from equation 1 and 2, you'll end up with 2 equations and 3 variables $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$. So, you're short one equation to close your system and uniquely identify all unknowns (if possible). Trick is, any of $x_1 - x_3$ can be free, you just pick one and try to express other ones using it. So, $x_3$ is not the only choice to be a free variable, but as soon as you pick one, other two are not free.

Comment: This text uses "free variable" with a different meaning than the usual one in which "free variable" is the opposite of "bound variable" (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)). Here "free variable" is being defined in terms of arbitrary properties like which variable is first in the graphical representation of the equations or which one has the lowest index. @Kaster: You seem to be using the term with its standard meaning. According to the text's definition, only $x_3$ is a free variable.

Answer (score 1):

The given system can be represented as an augmented matrix
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
2 & -4 & 2 & 1 & 11 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 2 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 9
\end{array}\right]
$$
We can row reduce this matrix to reduced row-echelon form
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}
\rref A =
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$$
This reduced system shows that the solutions to our system are of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\\ x_4\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 2+x_3\\ -1+x_3\\ x_3\\ 3\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\0\\3\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\\0\end{bmatrix}x_3
$$
Each of the variables $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_4$ can be written in terms of $x_3$. Hence $x_3$ is referred to as a "free variable" while $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_4$ are called "pivot variables".